# How to encrypt different messages in one encrypted text?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, encoding, cryptography

Here's an example for better understanding of the question:

```
2.0.0-p353 :003 > puts Base64.decode64 content
Glad to see we managed to get your attention! 
You'll find our message in the bottle. Choose one or more tools to open it; 
drop me a mail if you're interested in working together.

              $!'<
              ]!N3
          !9<Z]NWl!Z]N
            Q!]90!NW
             <6<K$E
             !'$*B0
             K-!N3!
             QW0o<!
             f$Z!fW
           <]]0K!<K!Q
       l]9NK!`Z<K6!-?$K6N
     !Z]NQ!f0!Z]<EE!`Z0!]90
    H!$!EN]!Z]NQ!$--!]90!fNW
    -!Z<EElf$EBZ!]N!]90!Z`'?
    0*]!E<K0!N3!lN`W!W0ZQNKZ
    0!3`EEZ]NQg1"LO^"OLFm"a[
    1"@%d%[+X=R^"(a^"+OIR=F1
    "IOX1"F%L7a%71["^O"=^"F=
    C1":%j1"1FI"+O4411[+X=R^
    "^mR1[+X=R^"[^OR"%.."^:1
    "R:X%[1"RmX%I=.O4.OOI"^O
    "^:1"[a(@1+^"F=L1"O4"mOa
    X"X1[ROL[1"4aFF[^ORh2#&Y
    2#JPe>M8#_P#&#\2Ye>,2#PY
    >2M_2/#&Y,;>_2,_bY2#PM#&
    #AeJ#)&\2/#\_&,D#b\>M8#\
    PJ2#G>)Y&Y>2\#PS2M\PbY,2
    /#)n#M2_5G>k#\_PS#&//#_;
    2#hPY/#J>G&MP#_P#_;2#\b)
    A2,_#G>M2#h;2M#\2M/>M8#b
       \#&#J&>G#5bGG\_PS


CLUE #1
def decode_char(ch):
    x = ord(ch) - 33
    return None if (x % 3) else ' ' if x < 3 else chr(x / 3 + 64)

CLUE #2
function decodeChar(ch) {
    var x = ch.charCodeAt(0) - 33
    if (String.fromCharCode(x % 3 + 64) != 'A')
        return null;
    else if (x < 3)
        return ' ';
    else
        return String.fromCharCode(x / 3 + 64)
}

CLUE #3
def decodeChar(c: Char): Option[Char] = c.toInt - 33 match {
    case 2              => Some(' ')
    case x if x % 3 > 1 => Some((x/3 + 64).toChar)
    case _              => None
}
 => nil
```

The functions listed below the bottle do decode the bottle in a different ways. For example, JS code gives this:

> "WE NOT ONLY USE JAVASCRIPT BUT COMPILE MORE LANGUAGES TO IT LIKE HAXE
>   ELM COFFEESCRIPT TYPESCRIPT STOP ADD THE PHRASE PYRAMIDOFDOOM TO THE
>   SUBJECT LINE OF YOUR RESPONSE FULL"

Other functions are giving different texts.

So the **question** here is: **How to encrypt different texts in one "bottle" (encrypted text)?**

Comment: You have given the problem you've got, but you have not really phrased a clear question.

Comment: Marcus, question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each character has a value encoded in it that denotes which algorithm is needed for decoding.

`return None if (x % 3)` -> Anything not a multiple of 3 (n%3 != 0) is ignored.

`if (String.fromCharCode(x % 3 + 64) != 'A') return null;` -> All characters *not* (n*3)+1, i.e. n%3 != 1, are ignored

`if x % 3 > 1 => ...` -> only characters with (n%3) > 1, i.e. n%3 = 2, are decoded, others are ignored.

EDIT:

The *encryption* can be inferred as

`c_output = ((c_input-64) * 3) + msg_no`

where `msg_no` is the number of the message (less than 3) the input character belongs to.

If you take a bigger number than 3 you can encode more different messages into the same stream. However, it is important that `c_output` is still in the valid range for the datatype, e.g. a single ASCII character or byte. With 3 different message streams, encoding a `µ` (code 181 in ASCII) is not possible: `(181-64) * 3 > 255`. Equally, `9` (code 57 in ASCII) cannot be encoded because `(57-64)*3 < 0`.